# How to apply switchable theme like twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a novice programmer, a college student with little knowledge about designing. I'm developing a microblogging website like twitter and I want to use pre-loaded styles(or themes) like twitter, I saw page source of a website with the same features, they din't seem to use different CSS files of may be I don't get it right. My question is, how can I apply this to my website? Please describe from basic as I don't have much knowledge about this things!
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

well , first you will need to give your users the ability to do some changes.Lets say you already have that.

What you will need is a base CSS file that has all the rules and styles except the ones you allow your users to specify ( or have some defaults for them).

After a user specifies the rules , generate a css file , store it in their user folder (or a database, but I do not recommend that) , then load that css in addition to the base css file you have , when someone logs into the profile of the User.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have a central CSS file defining a bunch of things that don't change, and then a secondary CSS file that provides the "theme". You'll have several of those secondary files, one for each theme. When building your page, you only include a `link` element for one of those files.

If you want to allow changing themes on-the-fly, you can do that by changing the `href` of that `link` element.

So for instance, if we assume a `link` like this:

```
<link id="themeStyle" href="green.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then this code changes it:

```
document.getElementById("themeStyle").href = "blue.css":
```

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/olepuh/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/olepuh/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <link id="themeStyle" href="/acofoy/1" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="group">
  <div><label><input name="theme" type="radio" value="1" checked>Green</label></div>
  <div><label><input name="theme" type="radio" value="2">Blue</label></div>
  <div><label><input name="theme" type="radio" value="3">Red</label></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {

  var buttons = document.getElementById("group").getElementsByTagName("input");
  var index;

  for (index = 0; index < buttons.length; ++index) {
    buttons[index].onclick = setStyle;
  }

  function setStyle() {
    document.getElementById("themeStyle").href = "/acofoy/" + this.value;
  }

})();
```

Note: I used numbers for the values rather than names because I was using JSBin. In real life, of course, I'd use names (`green.css`, `blue.css`, `red.css`, etc.).